Access Environment Variables in Flutter Web
I am pushing my Flutter Web project to Vercel.
Currently using Supabase as backend.
I need to access the SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY environment variable for my web app to work.
I am aware of the Vercel Environment Variables but don't know how to access them client-side.
For node.js you can do something like process.env.VARIABLE but I cannot find dart client documentation for the same thing.
I cannot do --dart-define because my build command will be too long.
What are my options?

Do you want to access an environment variable which is defined on the server? Or do you want to add configuration values to your dart code?

try using a makefile

@PeterKoltai I want to acces environment variables that are defined in Vercel as explained here https://vercel.com/docs/projects/environment-variables, however, I do not know how to access them from the client side so that when I upload the flutter web project, it can access the server side env variables.

@Md.YeasinSheikh would I have to upload the makefile to version control? or to vercel? in the first case, my sensitive keys that I define will be exposed.

This question is similar to: Setting environment variables in Flutter. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. (If you know the keys of the vercel defined values, you can read them in your app using the syntax provided in the answers of this post)

@TomasWard If the environment variable contains sensitive data imo you should not expose it to the client. If you still decide to do so you have to implement a server side endpoint that returns the environment variable from the server to the client.
